# How particles in a wave influence adjacent particles?

Tags: waves

An explanation for an almost identical question is posted at: [How do particles in a wave make the next particles move?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172533/how-do-particles-in-a-wave-make-the-next-particles-move)

The explanation given assumes an up and down motion.
However, my question is a little different. The setup is fixed a rope to a table at one end, and held the rope so that it was perpendicular to the ground and then lifted up your hand slowly so that one end was raised.

Now, if you give the rope only the downwards motion, a wave still forms. There is some upward force on the rope but I can't understand where it comes from.

An example of this is found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJhsKexCmW4) at 9:00. He explains a transfer of potential energy takes place but I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how that happens.